# How to wait for page fully loaded CasperJS

Tags: npm, tdd, casperjs, wait

I am trying to login on my website using an array of `accounts` in CasperJS.

```
casper.start()
    .then(function() {
        accounts.forEach(function(account) {
            casper.thenOpen('http://mywebsite/login', function() {
                casper.fill('form.form-type1', account, true);
                casper.waitForSelector(".widgetContainer-widget-title", function() {
                    var elemsCount= this.evaluate(function() {
                        var elem= $('.widget-personal');
                        return elem.length;
                    });
                    this.echo(surveysCount + ' elemsCount ' + account['username'] + '\n');
                });
            });
        });
    });

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('----------- Donenzo, enjoy! ------------\n');
    this.exit();
});
```

Now, the code is working fine but the number returned is always 0, because when `widgetContainer-widget-title` is fully rendered, `widget-personal` is not yet ready, hence it cannot find any element at that point in time so returns 0 and this is because my website is an Angular app and regrettably has a delay when communicating to the DB. Any idea of how to wait until a page is completely rendered to apply a test?

Comment: I have also tried `waitUntilVisible()` for my desired selector, and that times out, and there is no way it can exceed a timeout of more than 5s

Answer (score 1):

[ANSWER]

I worked around it by waiting on the `.widget-personal` element itself, rather than its parent. It is an ugly workaround but it works, and then I am catching the errors thrown by the timeout as described per: [casper.waitForSelector, timeout and error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678941/casper-waitforselector-timeout-and-error-handling)